# Where is Openfire Server Directory on Mac?

Tags: linux, openfire

I am trying to work with Openfire server on a Mac. I currently have setup the server to work with an embedded database, but I don't know or can't place the html/php files that I want to use with the server. The Openfire index page states this in Server Information -> Server Properties:

Server Directory: /usr/local/openfire

The problem with this directory is that I can't locate it with finder, and when I try to "cd" into the openfire directory through Terminal (Linux) I get this error:

-bash: cd: openfire: Permission denied

Does anyone know a way around this, or how might I place the files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entering super user mode first is one solution:

`sudo su`

and then:

`cd /usr/local/openfire`

Once you're done, type `exit` to get out of super user mode.

Could I ask, why are you trying to add files to that directory though?

Comment: Yes, this had worked! I was able to go into the directory. I downloaded mamp to host some websites, and in ht-docs

Comment: Yes, this had worked! I was able to go into the directory. I am not a server specialist, but when I downloaded MAMP to host some websites I was able to put some files in the 'ht-docs' folder, which was used to host the websites. MAMP does not seem to work with XMPP protocol, I believe, b/c the website ports are different from the xmpp port (not too sure about the port terminology there). This is why I downloaded the Openfire server, b/c it is suppose to be compatible with the XMPP protocol. I was hoping to place my php website files in: usr/local/openfire in order to host the websites.

Comment: Now that I am in su mode, my next question would be, how to place website files within here? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you're mixing a normal website with XMPP. You certainly don't want to mix MAMP and Openfire together. MAMP uses Apache to serve HTTP requests, Openfire is itself a server that handles the XMPP protocol. How are you hoping to integrate Openfire with your website? That is the most important question

Comment: Oh at the time I was just creating an XMPP client and needed a separate XMPP server to test the client.